# how to automatically update the version of JS file in url

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, version

I have a JavaScript file which i am loading on different pages in my mvc application.

whenever i change my JavaScript file I have to change the version of JS file on every page manually .

```
<script src="~/Areas/Streamer/Scripts/global.js?v=1"></script>
```

I want to do something like so I want to change only one thing on 1 location and version will be changed automatically on every page . Is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("path").ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"); ;

 <script src="~/Areas/Streamer/Scripts/global.js?v=@lastModified"></script>
```

You can make this as your static variable and put this code inside global.asax . or you have choice to run it everytime

Answer (score 2):

Include your js file to _Layout.cshtml and concat current datetime with your js file. It will always load the updated version of your file.

```cs
<script src="~/Areas/Streamer/Scripts/global.js?v=@DateTime.Now"></script>
```